# Edge detection gives pixel ids, why?

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, canny-edge-detector

This questions is in conjugation with this one [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/connecting-edges-detected-by-an-edge-detector/)!

Canny edge detector gives ids of pixels in an image. Not the locations of the edges. To be specific, after all it should be an edge between two pixels. Any implementation that actually gives arcs not pixels?

One solution i can make is that if i have a pixel, i can simply take the bottom edge and right edge for consistency but it might disconnect my feature. 
Edit: Edge is referred to an arc between 2 pixels. 
Something smarter?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question: IIRC the Canny edge detector uses a Sobel operator underneath, which is essentially a central difference - i.e. the edges are centered on pixels, not between pixels.

Comment: I didnt know its sobel based. Still I need arcs between pixels not 'on' the pixels. I gotta way i guess. because i specifically need edges along the arcs.

Comment: Are you trying to get curves or contour chain (in the form of "chain code", or linked lists of edge pixels)? If so, please edit your question.